# PyParsing, matching lines beginning with White

Tags: python, pyparsing

Given following grammar sensitive to newlines, how can i ignore comments beginning with spaces?

The `pp.LineStart() + pp.Optional(pp.White(" \t")) + '#'` does not match lines  beginning with spaces as one would expect.

```
import pyparsing as pp
pp.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')

def Line(expr): return expr + pp.Suppress(pp.LineEnd())

foo = Line(pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas))))

parser = pp.OneOrMore(foo)

comment = '#' + pp.restOfLine()
parser.ignore(pp.LineStart() + pp.Optional(pp.White(" \t")) + pp.Optional(comment) + pp.LineEnd())
parser.ignore(comment)

text = """

 foo abc
# comment
bar # comment
"""

results = parser.parseString(text, parseAll=True)
assert list(results[0]) == ['foo', 'abc']

text = """

foo abc
 # comment
bar
"""

results = parser.parseString(text, parseAll=True)

print "ok"
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why your text strings have lines that are 200+ characters long, because of trailing whitespace? If not ,please edit them out.

Comment: pasting from terminal gone wrong, corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines containing just a comment can leave a dangling LineEnd in the input. Change parser to:

```
parser = pp.OneOrMore(foo | pp.LineEnd().suppress())
```

Comment: FYI - working on this motivated me to expand the exceptions reported by pyparsing. Now instead of just "Error occurred, expected <something> (location line and column info)" they will now read "Error occurred, expected <something>, found `<this other thing instead>` (location line and column info)". Will make errors like this easier to diagnose and correct.